# Linq Foreign Key | How to display only the elements with a specific foreign key?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have two tables: Book and Chapter

```
Book
ID
Title
Author

Chapter
ChapterID
BookID
Title
```

I have a method in the Controller which is supposed to display a list of all the Chapters of a Book. However, it displays all the elements in the Chapter table, instead of the ones that match the BookID

Here is my method:

```
public ActionResult ViewChapters()
    {
        var chapters = db.Chapters
                             .Where(x => x.BookId ==  x.Book.ID)
                             .Include(x => x.Book).ToList();
        return View(chapters);
    }
```

I guess it's something wrong with my linq query.

Comment: `x => x.BookId ==  x.Book.ID` always returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the id of the book to the method, otherwise there's no way the code knows which book you're referencing.

```cs
public ActionResult ViewChapters(Guid bookId)
{
    var chapters = db.Chapters
                         .Where(x => x.BookId == bookId)
                         .Include(x => x.Book).ToList();
    return View(chapters);
}
```

The `Where` predicate evaluates each item in `db.Chapters` and only keeps the items where the predicate returns true. As Fabio mentions in the comments, when you compare `x.BookId == x.Book.ID`, the result is true for each item in the `db.Chapters` collection.

Comment: Yes, but how can I initialize the parameter i'm passing to the controller to be the bookId? Because now it doesn't display anything. What else should I change for bookId to have a propper value when is being passed? I'm sorry, but I'm a little new to ASP.NET.

Comment: I guess this is an API method (inside a ApiController) ? Also, what type is `BookId` (I used Guid as an example here).

Comment: Mine is actually a int. From what I've been finding online, could it have something to do with the routing?

Comment: You need a routing attribute indeed, f.e. `[Route("view-chapters/{bookId}")]` then send a request to `/view-chapters/5` where 5 would be the book id.